# Array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, initialization

```
Border[] _headerBorder = new Border[] {
    new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{},
    new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{},
    new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{},
    new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}, new Border{}
};
```

How can I shorten this type of declaration?

Answer (score 4):

Shorten means what?

I would better go with the below If I need to create an array with 20 elements.

```
Border[] _headerBorder = new Border[20];

for (int i = 0; i < _headerBorder.Length; i++)
{
    _headerBorder[i] = new Border();
}
```

**Edit**: As per the comment by @Rand random, you could also do it like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _headerBorder.Length; i++)
    _headerBorder[i] = new ();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `for` loop flattened into a single line of code:

```cs
var _headerBorder = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => new Border()).ToArray();
```